# Regex pattern in salesforce apex

Tags: regex, apex

I am new to regex.

I have a String formatted like below

```
Street Name 
City, StateCode ZipNumber
```

for example, the string can be like

```
50 Connecticut Avenue
Norwalk, CT 06850
```

or

```
123 6th Avenue
New York, NY 10013
```

or

```
4TH Highway 6
Rule, TX 79547
```

I am trying to construct a regex here. 
[image]
But cannot proceed as I have a little idea about regex.
Can you please help me?

Comment: What is your expected output, and do you have many of these addresses across two lines, or is two lines all that you have?

Comment: Why not simply split over linefeed then split the second line over comma? A regex will probably just do the same in a less efficient way, e.g. `([^\n]*)\n([^,]*),(.*)`

Comment: My expected output is to catch the streetname, city, statecode and zipNumber. The two lines is all that I have

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/8QKSeY/2) might work but it's very tolerant, it won't check that your zip number actually is a number, that the street starts by a number, etc. I just implemented in regex the split over linefeed then comma I previously mentionned. I also used named groups which you might not have a use for, just remove the `?<name>` at the start of each capturing groups if you refer to them by index instead of name or if they aren't implemented in apex

Comment: @Aaron: I think, your solution will work in my case. BTW, I have modified https://regex101.com/r/sKHpvY/1 and it is not capturing the 1st Character in state code.

Comment: You need to put the `{2}` quantifier inside the capturing group (`(?<StateCode>[A-Z]{2})` instead of `(?<StateCode>[A-Z]){2}`), otherwise it captures twice a single character and only the result of the last capture is visible.

Comment: Oh, Thanks man! You can add an answer here so that I can accept it.

Comment: You're welcome, just did so. Might be worth using `\d{5}` instead of `\d+` in the Zip capturing group btw if zip codes are always 5 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might be enough :

```
^(?<Street>[^\n]+)\n(?<City>[^,]+), (?<StateCode>[A-Z]{2}) (?<Zip>\d+)$
```

It captures the following segments in different groups :

- the first line in a group named `Street`
- the part of the second line which precedes the comma in a group named `City`
- the next two capital letters in a group named `StateCode`
- the following digits in a group named `Zip`